# knockout validation user defined rules

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout-validation

I'm using knockout validation to validate a form. Each field has a custom set of rules.

In my application an administrator should have the rights to chose some rules from a predefined set of rules for a specific field. I will have button for each input field that will open a modal where all the rules will be displayed is a check box and the administrator should be able to chose from them an define custom *params* or *messages*.

My question is: How can I define the rules and then pass them to `ko.observable.extend(rules)` so I could change the ones that I validate against in the application view.

I tried sending them as a string but no success:

```
var lastNameRules = '{ minLength: 2, required: true }';
var lastName = ko.observable().extend(lastNameRules);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, so I'm posting the solution. I am declaring the rules in an array as structures and then I apply each rule to the observable:

```
var rules = [{ required: true }, { minLength: 3 }, { maxLength: 10 }];

    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        lastName.extend(rules[i]);
    }
```

This way all the rules are implemented.

**Edit:** Other way would be to push some rules into the rules array of the observable:

```
lastName.rules().push({ rule: "email", params: true });
```

This way the *extend* has to be declared before adding the rules, because of the additional functionality that is added to the  observable. Otherwise there will be no *rules* array as a field in the observable.